# eval ssh command in variable

Tags: bash, ssh, eval

I am trying to execute commands via `ssh` remotely. But I have the calling command saved as variable such as:

```
SSH_CMD="ssh -i path_to/identity"
SSH_USER=user
SSH_DST=server
dir1=dir1
dir2=dir2
```

now if I

```
eval $SSH_CMD $SSH_USER@$SSH_DST "mkdir $dir1 && mv $dir1 $dir2 && touch $dir2"
```

I get errors (they are typically: `mv: cannot stat 'dir1': No such file or directory`)

but if I:

```
ssh -i path_to/identity $SSH_USER@$SSH_DST "mkdir $dir1 && mv $dir1 $dir2 && touch $dir2"
```

That works. So the problem seems in how I am handling `eval`. What is the correct way?

Comment: Related, if not a dupe: [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946)

Comment: Reading material: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ#BashFAQ.2F050.I.27m_trying_to_put_a_command_in_a_variable.2C_but_the_complex_cases_always_fail.21)

Comment: @glennjackman I quite disagree with that, the name of an executable can be variable (system to system different) and being able to abstract it is quite important

Comment: That's what the `$PATH` variable is for, so you can specify the "ssh" command you want to use. Or are you saying that on system1, it's called "ssh" and on system2 it has a different name like "secure_shell"?

Comment: @glennjackman why not? It does not necessarily be the `ssh` but some executable that actually takes the same or similar syntax...

Comment: @leosenko Yes the _name_ of a command. Which variable in your code contains the name of a command? Note that `SSH_CMD` contains options too, and relies on the shell to do the word-splitting and filename globbing without messing it up.

Answer (score 3):

```
eval $SSH_CMD $SSH_USER@$SSH_DST "mkdir $dir1 && mv $dir1 $dir2 && touch $dir2"
```

This is practically the same as running

```
eval "$SSH_CMD $SSH_USER@$SSH_DST mkdir $dir1 && mv $dir1 $dir2 && touch $dir2"
```

`eval` joins the arguments it gets to a single string, and then runs that as shell command. In particular, the `&&` acts on the local side, so the shell runs first `ssh ... mkdir dir1`, and if that succeeds, it runs `mv dir1 dir2`, etc. `mkdir` runs on the remote host, but `mv` on the local host, where `dir1` doesn't exist.

---

There's no need to use `eval` here. Your first command would do without it:

```
$SSH_CMD $SSH_USER@$SSH_DST "mkdir $dir1 && mv $dir1 $dir2 && touch $dir2"
```

When `$SSH_CMD` is *not* quoted, it gets split to the three words `ssh`, `-i`, and `path_to/identity` just as you want. This works, but is somewhat unclean, and you'd get into trouble if you had to include arguments with whitespace within `$SSH_CMD`, or used glob characters there.

If you need to store a variable number of command arguments, like in  `SSH_CMD`, it's better to use an array. Also, quote the other variables to prevent word splitting, too:

```
ssh_cmd=(ssh -i path_to/identity)
ssh_user=user
ssh_host=server
dir1=dir1
dir2=dir2
"${ssh_cmd[@]}" "$ssh_user@$ssh_host" "mkdir $dir1 && mv $dir1 $dir2 && touch $dir2"
```

See [BashFAQ 050: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) and [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

I see no reason to use `eval` here, it's simply introducing the potential for many vulnerabilities into your command.

You should store options in an array when possible instead of a variable like so:

```
SSH_OPTS=( -i path_to/identity )
SSH_USER=user
SSH_DST=server
dir1=dir1
dir2=dir2
```

---

Then you should ensure to **always** double quote your variables:

```
ssh "${SSH_OPTS[@]}" "${SSH_USER}@${SSH_DST}" "mkdir $dir1 && mv $dir1 $dir2 && touch $dir2"
```

Comment: That last bit, if it was sourced or executed by a shell (it's not clear in the question) it would try to run `-i` as a command.  And now it's updated in the question.

Comment: My bad, the SSH_COMMAND is quoted, see the edit. I apologize. What would be the more general case if I wanted to keep the name `ssh` stored in a variable as well?

Comment: @leosenko: The only reason I could think of to store the `ssh` command in a variable would be to specify the full path and ensure you are using a specific version of a command.  However you can just add it into the beginning of the `SSH_OPTS` array if you desire.  I would consider that obfuscated.